# How do I interpret at Java thread that is RUNNABLE but with no stack trace?

Tags: java, debugging

I am debugging a legacy Java application, and the thread dump (obtained via `jstack`) contains some entries like the following:

```
"Thread-8" prio=10 tid=0x0000000055f2c800 nid=0x49bf runnable [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

That's it. No stack trace.

What's going on here? How do I locate the Java code executing in this thread?

Comment: Why did you post this as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: The name of the thread is no help at all; they should always name threads properly.

Comment: @noahz: I didn't have enough confidence in it. I made it an answer and we'll see if the community likes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread isn't (or wasn't) executing Java code. It's handling tasks not implemented in Java that weren't directly requested by any Java caller. For example, if the corresponding OS thread just caught a signal.

Comment: Perhaps these are the theads executing due to `jstack` itself? Can I add a flag to jstack that reveals the native frames?

Comment: The Java application was calling into a C library via JNI that started native Linux threads.